# Ubuntu: execute a terminal output inside Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, make

I have a command that spits as an output another command. I'd like to run this output in a makefile script.

The simpler command I could reproduce is

```
awsecrpush:
    VAR=$$( sudo echo "ls -lah" ) | bash -c "sudo -s $$VAR"
```

What are my results:

- Running **make**

```
    $ make
    VAR=$( sudo echo "ls -lah" ) | bash -c "sudo -s $VAR"
    echo $VAR
    {empty output}
```

- But running **ls -lah**, it works as expected. That's what I want from  my makefile

```
$ ls -lah
total 405
-rw-rw-r--  1 garry garry  405 jul 22 10:59 Makefile
```

That's only to simplify my question because I have a complex command to execute.

I need this approach just because I need append SUDO in front of *ls -lah*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, by using `|`, you're running the two commands (the assignment of `VAR` and the `sudo` command using it) in separate subshells, so you're setting the variable in a shell while trying to use it in another one.

Furthermore, there's really no need for a pipe, since you're not really passing any output from the first command to the standard input of the second (`ls` doesn't really take anything on stdin.)

Just replacing `|` with a `;` should make this work for you. (Using `&&` would also be good, since then it only runs the `sudo` part if the command generating the contents of the variable succeeds.)

Note that you need both in the same line, since `make` normally spawns a shell for each separate line in the recipe. You need both running on the same shell, otherwise you will set `VAR` from one shell and try to consume it from a separate shell, which will again not work.

```
awsecrpush:
        VAR=$$( sudo echo "ls -lah" ) && bash -c "sudo -s $$VAR"
```

---

Another possibility is to use a Make variable instead. That's somewhat more flexible in that you might not need to worry so much about subshells.

Assuming you have GNU make, you can use [the shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) to run the first command and save its output in a Make variable.

```
awsecrpush:
        VAR := $(shell sudo echo "ls -lah")
        sudo -s $(VAR)
```